# Android RunTimeError: Java.lang.RunTimeException: Unable to Instantiate activity

Tags: android, fatal-error

I am getting the following error every time I run my android app on an AVD. The app crashes almost instantly upon running it:

```
    08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.zamani.randomizedworkout/com.zamani.randomizedworkout.MainScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.zamani.randomizedworkout.MainScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.zamani.randomizedworkout-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.zamani.randomizedworkout-2, /system/lib]]
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.zamani.randomizedworkout.MainScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.zamani.randomizedworkout-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.zamani.randomizedworkout-2, /system/lib]]
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
08-24 02:18:01.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1860):     ... 11 more
```

Also, here is my AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zamani.randomizedworkout"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.zamani.randomizedworkout" />

    <application>
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.zamani.randomizedworkout"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.zamani.randomizedworkout.WorkoutScreen"
            android:label="com.zamani.randomizedworkout.MyActivityLib:string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Some additional info regarding my issue: I have included both of my activities in my AndroidManifest, which is shown above, so unless I am missing something I'm not sure that's the issue I am having. My app worked perfectly fine until I upgraded the SDK version from 17 to 18 a few days back, so maybe that is part of my problem. I've checked several other StackOverflow threads on similar issues, and I didn't find a solution that solved my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That didn't seem to help, as I already had the Android Private Libraries selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.zamani.randomizedworkout.MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem, as it still crashes with the same error when I run it.

Comment: @MikeZ which is your main activity? replace MainScreen with the name of Main Activity in the above code

Comment: @Raghunadan MainScreen is the main activity of the project. I'm using a library in which my activities extend a "Screen" superclass to simplify some aspects. But the application worked perfectly fine up until I changed from version 17 to 18. Perhaps I should try creating a project from scratch and copy my code and activities into that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but restarting the device after installing my app solved the problem. But now the problem is, I have to do it every time to be able to run the app.